# Actionscript 2.0 and 3.0: Dragging Dynamic Image and not being replaced by another

Tags: actionscript-3, image, dynamic, drag-and-drop, replace

I have a function that displays an image on top of a movie clip but when you click another image, it of course replaces the current image. I don't know how to stop it from replacing the image, that way I can make an image appear and drag it over somewhere on the stage and then make a different image appear and drag that somewhere else, too. and what is the drag event for Actionscript 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite or MovieClip [startDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) and [stopDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#stopDrag%28%29) methods.
also i don't understand the following:

> function that displays an image on top of a movie clip but when you click another image, it of course replaces the current image

how do images get inside of your swf (library, embed, loader)?
why are they replacing each other on MouseEvent.CLICK?

according to my current vision of your problem [Event.stopImmediatePropagation() or Event.stopPropagation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29) in MouseEvent.CLICK handler function may help